# how to find all corrected indexes files in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

we have 3 kafka  machines in our cluster ,

kafka version - **0.10.0.2.6** ,

and 3 zookeeper servers version - **3.4.6**

we have a problem that one of the kafka broker cant start , and seems this is because the corrupted indexes files

we noticed that kafka log ( /var/log/kafka/server.log ) , on each kafka machine indicate about thousands of corrupted indexes files as the following

*example from server.log*

```
[2019-02-25 12:34:44,907] INFO Completed load of log topic.pop.control.gtp.enrichment-38 with 14 log segments and log end offset 200458117 in 1583 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:45,044] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 8068079 which is no larger than the base offset 8068079.}. deleting /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.timeindex, /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.index and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:45,217] INFO Recovering unflushed segment 8068079 in log topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50. (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:45,255] INFO Completed load of log topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50 with 6 log segments and log end offset 8095839 in 347 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:45,261] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.wnr-38/00000000001979940988.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 1979940988 which is no larger than the base offset 1979940988.}. deleting /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.wnr-38/00000000001979940988.timeindex, /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.wnr-38/00000000001979940988.index and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:47,607] INFO Recovering unflushed segment 1979940988 in log topic.pop.pri.wnr-38. (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:48,872] INFO Completed load of log topic.pop.pri.wnr-38 with 21 log segments and log end offset 1980403224 in 3617 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:48,935] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp-88/00000000000216947511.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 216947511 which is no larger than the base offset 216947511.}. deleting /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp-88/00000000000216947511.timeindex, /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp-88/00000000000216947511.index and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:52,436] INFO Recovering unflushed segment 216947511 in log topic.pop.control.gtp-88. (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:54,508] INFO Completed load of log topic.pop.control.gtp-88 with 21 log segments and log end offset 217830559 in 5635 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:54,531] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.lop-10/00000000000000000000.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 0 which is no larger than the base offset 0.}. deleting /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.lop-10/00000000000000000000.timeindex, /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.lop-10/00000000000000000000.index and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-25 12:34:57,540] INFO Recovering unflushed segment 0 in log topic.pop.pri.lop-10. (kafka.log.Log)
```

*example of corrupted indexes files*

```
/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.index
/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.wnr-38/00000000001979940988.index
/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp-88/00000000000216947511.index
/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.pri.lop-10/00000000000000000000.index
```

what is the right approach in order to delete the corrupted indexes files?

one option is to find the corrupted indexes files from the servcer.log ( on each kafka machine ) and make a list , and then delete them on each kafka broker as

```
rm -f /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.index
```

but this approach not promise us that log – server.log include all the corrupted indexes files , so maybe there are more corrupted indexes file that not mentioned in the log!
so how to find all files that are corrupted by command or any other syntax that show all corrupted indexes files?

I think that if we have this list , then we can create simple script in bash that will run on the list and remove the files automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At startup, Kafka will automatically rebuild all index files that look corrupted. You can see that in the log line, it says "rebuilding index":

> Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 8068079 which is no larger than the base offset 8068079.}. deleting /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.timeindex, /var/kafka/kafka-logs/topic.pop.control.gtp.state-50/00000000000008068079.index and **rebuilding index**...

You typically get "corrupted" indexes when Kafka does not shutdown cleanly

Comment: so do you mean that we need to wait until all indexes will be fix ?

Comment: but in case we cant start the kafka , then how it will be fix it?

Answer (score -1):

You can add additional time out in your shut down script to avoid such corruption.
Also, best way to clear indexes is removing the actual folder rm -rf of the folder where the index is stored. this path is mentioned in server.properties. example "log.dir=/tmp/abc/test/topic-data"

Remove one at a time and restart.